# How Can You Use JOIN Statement From Excel Source Data To SQL Server Data For New Data Set For Lookup In Data Flow Task of SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, lookup, script-component

I have an `Excel Source` that connected to a `Lookup Transformation` that is then connected to an `OLE DB Command` that holds a stored procedure to Insert my data into SQL Server.

The following is the query I want within the Data Flow before the `Lookup` Transformation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EFF f
LEFT OUTER JOIN OH o  ON f.No = o.Name
LEFT OUTER JOIN Ay a  ON f.No = A.Reg
INNER JOIN      Oh ot ON a.Num = ot.name
WHERE f.Type LIKE  'z%' 
 AND  o.is null
```

So basically, I want to use this query to do a `Lookup` on using the `Excel Source` data...would I use a `Script Component`?

Comment: What problem are you having? Why doesn't the Lookup work?

Comment: Are we to assume EFF, OH and AY are worksheets in Excel or something? How does this differ from your source?

Comment: @JohnSaunders The `Lookup` won't work because there was already a lot of data in the database.  There was a stored procedure similar to above but instead of `SELECT *` it was `UPDATE f SET f.no = a.Num FROM...`  Because this data was rectified outside of the ETL Process, I need to use the SELECT statement in my question to run on the Excel Source data in my Data Flow Task for the `Lookup`

Comment: @billinkc Please see response to JohnSaunders..There was  a bunch of data that was rectified outside the ETL Process...I need to run a Join from the Excel Source data to find the rectified data to Lookup on so that no duplicated data (with unrectified data) is inserted into DB.  That's Why I need to get the results of this SELECT query before it hits the Lookup

Comment: @JeffOrris But I still don't know what EFF, OH and AY are. If they're tables, then you can do all of that in a query on the Lookup Transform. If they're worksheets in excel, then you'd need to use a Cache Connection Manager for your lookup and use merge joins x3 to populate the CCM

Comment: @billinkc EFF would be the Excel Worksheets.  OH and AY are tables in SQL Server...sorry for not clarifying that

Answer (score 0):

I would use SSIS to  load the Excel data into a  SQL Server table and add the resulting table to the query. I assume the main data source is SQL Server.

Comment: I need to run the SELECT statement in my question on the Excel data in my DataFlow before it hits the Lookup

Comment: 1) Load the data from Excel into SQL Server. 2) Run the select statement 3) Do the lookup. What am I missing?

Comment: The excel data needs to be joined to SQL Server tables so get result set needed for Lookup

Comment: Edited question title